# AVURLAsset cannot find video track

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, uivideoeditorcontroller

I use `UIVideoEditorController` to trim a video. After editing, in the delegate, I try to remix the video with other media. However, `[AVURLAsset trackWithMediaType:]` is unable to find video track. The code is as follow:

```
- (void)video:(NSString*)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo {
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    if(asset == nil) {
      NSLog(@"Cannot create AVURLAsset");
      return;
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Asset: %@", asset);
    }

    if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].count == 0) {
      NSLog(@"No Video Track");
      return;
    } else if([asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].count == 0) {
      NSLog(@"No Audio Track");
      return;
    }
    // Follow up codes hidden intentionally
}
```

The Console log prints:

```
2014-10-15 13:35:45.913 TestVideoTrim[3278:1191544] Asset: <AVURLAsset: 0x178229e00, URL = /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/96E7C0FF-92EB-44F7-8E35-B29FD0E58302/tmp/trim.EC3FB214-9907-411D-B3A3-75 ... 41E5.MOV>
2014-10-15 13:35:45.981 TestVideoTrim[3278:1191544] No Video Track
```

However, when I go to Photo App and play the trimmed video, the video plays well with audio. What could be the reason of unable to find video track?

p.s. the delegate function's `NSError` returns `null`, representing there is no error occurred when editing the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];
```

with

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```